# Changing grouped tables border radius

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, core-graphics

Is it possible to change how radius of the grouped UITableView? The rounded corners are way to drastic for my design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the only way to do this is to provide your own background images for your table cells. You can provide 3 images to have a rounded feel to the `UITableView` like Apple Does.

in
`- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`
set the cell's backgroundView to a `UIView` with the image you want based on the cell index. This will allow you to set the Top, Middle and Bottom.

This is a pretty good article

http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/easy-custom-uitableview-drawing.html

just be sure to `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:`

Answer (score 0):

No, it isn't. You can duplicate it though with a standard tableview and a couple custom background images.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change both `cell.backgroundView` and `cell.selectedBackgroundView` with a view of your choice.