# TableView corner radius different in iOS6

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, ios6

I have a simple app with a grouped UITableView. On the far left of each cell I have a thumbnail image and have manually created the top and bottom images to have curves to match the corners of the grouped table view.

This has worked well until iOS6. It appears the radius is slightly different which leaves me with gaps.

So that I can keep it looking consistent between iOS5 and 6, is there a way to alter the corner radius? I've tried altering the cell.backgroundView.layer.cornerRadius but it makes no difference.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I put the bulk of the tableview together in the Storyboard builder, but can post some of my code from the controller file if it helps. I was thinking was the cellForRowAtIndexPath method I needed to focus on, would you like me to copy & paste that? (P.S. first-time poster so apologies if I get the etiquette wrong)

Comment: Have you checked out these links? 

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9027874/changing-grouped-tables-border-radius](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9027874/changing-grouped-tables-border-radius)

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10245084/changing-corner-radius-of-a-grouped-uitableview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10245084/changing-corner-radius-of-a-grouped-uitableview)

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106861/round-corners-on-uitableview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106861/round-corners-on-uitableview)

Comment: Do u want tableview corners rounded @Phil

Comment: if so simply import QuartzCore and add UIView then add tablview inside view then view.tblview.layer.cornerRadious=5.0f; view setclipToBounds=YES;

Comment: Or else Simply u can set tblview.layer.cornerRadious=5.0f

Comment: @jbryson links will get you what you want. But it is likely easier to just make a second image for iOS6+ and conditionally load the images

Comment: Try  cell.layer.cornerRadius = 10.5;
     cell.clipsToBounds = YES;

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting this after the cornerRadius?

```
cell.backgroundView.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

> Setting this value to YES causes subviews to be clipped to the bounds of the receiver. If set to NO, subviews whose frames extend beyond the visible bounds of the receiver are not clipped. The default value is NO.
>   [UIView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html)